# Background Worker access from separate class

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I get an object reference is required for non-static field error when attempting to call OnProgressChanged and OnCheckCancel in separate class. It's a simple syntax error, but I can't figure it out.

I used the code from this link: [BackgroundWorker cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097968/backgroundworker-cancellation)

I can execute the code when the search engine code is included within the form, but I need to make it and many other methods in my class library support backgroundworkers.

```
//**** Windows Form code (Worker.cs)
public partial class Worker : Form 
{
    bwSearchEngine bwSE = new bwSearchEngine();

    public Worker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }
    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // set arguments
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(arguments);
    }
    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        bwSE.ProgressChanged += (s, pe) => worker.ReportProgress(pe.ProgressPercentage, pe.UserState);
        bwSE.CheckCancel += (sender1, e1) => e1.Cancel = worker.CancellationPending;

        e.Result = Search();
    }
}

//**** Engine code (bwSearchEngine.cs)

public event ProgressChangedEventHandler ProgressChanged;
public event EventHandler<CancelEventArgs> CheckCancel;

protected virtual void OnProgressChanged(int progress, string message)
{
    if (ProgressChanged != null)
    {
        ProgressChanged(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(progress, message));
    }
}
protected virtual bool OnCheckCancel()
{
    EventHandler<CancelEventArgs> handler = CheckCancel;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        CancelEventArgs e = new CancelEventArgs();
        handler(this, e);
        return e.Cancel;
    }
    return false;
}

public class Extensions
{
    public static List<HookSet> get_Extensions(string word, SQLiteDataSet hayfield)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr ...)
        {
            // Do processing
            if (results.Count > 0 && results.Count % 100 == 0)
            {
                OnProgressChanged(0, results.Count.ToString()); // ERROR ERROR
                if (OnCheckCancel()) // ERROR ERROR
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (results);
}
```

Comment: _OnProgressChanged_ is an event defined in the class _bwSearchEngine_ It is normal that you can't use it inside the Extensions class without using an instance of the _bwSearchEngine_ class.

Comment: Create a new public static class where the two events can write data.  The other classes can read data.  Rather than having event make the changes I usually crate a state class that I pass into the background worker so the code can change values rather than events.

Comment: The Extensions class is a subclass of bwSearchEngine so it is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I found a (somewhat undesirable solution). The class method get_Extensions is a static method and it's not possible to call a non-static method OnProgressChanged() from that. If I make the latter a static method then I can't add events to it from the BackgroundWorker. So, it seems I have to make everything related non-static, and create an instance of the class before using it, ... until I can find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I added the BackgroundWorker as a static method. Instead of adding the BackgroundWorker to the form in design mode, I added it to the constructor, and adjusted the code to accomodate the static bw.

```
    private readonly static BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    public Worker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bw.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.ProgressChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```